# Memcache module is working but with a strange error

Tags: caching

I have Memcache enabled both on Drupal and the server... It seems to be configured fine on the server-end (both by port & Settings.php).

If am being accurate, [PSI](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) grades even went up in about 4-5 points... So seemingly my site does use Memcache... And yet, Cron gives a strange error:

> PECL Memcache version 2.2.5 is unsupported. Please update to 3.0.6 or
>   newer.

Tried to Google the error (or part of it) and found just nothing... I've also spoke with the server's support team and one of them told me to ignore this error... I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do... Will glad for the advice of Veteran drupal developers...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Not supported" doesn't necessarily mean that it shouldn't work at all. I guess in this case it only means you shouldn't complain in case something breaks.

You may want to check if you can install a newer version of Memcache on your platform, just to be sure and future-proof.

Comment: So it's the server-side software that isn't updated... Right? (I am on a shared server, I hope they will allow it).

Comment: @benos right, only your sysadmin can perform update.There is few reasons not to do it, and a lot more to do it. Things may break when upgrading major version. On the other hand, there was some major improvements, too.

Comment: Yes shared server admins tend to be very conservative when it comes to updating software. I think they prefer to possibly prevent 1 problem rather than letting 1000 users benefit from the latest version.

Comment: A small note, after enabling "Memcache statistics at the bottom of each page" it seems that the software is working anyway.